# SP2010 How to Determine if SharePoint Content Database is in support mode

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have a legacy content database of SharePoint 2007 which I need to upgrade to SharePoint 2010 (and then SP2013) and I feel it is not in support mode. SP Admins pull information out using Select statements in Stage and I feel they might have put the database in unsupported mode.

Is there a way I can determine if the content db that I am trying to migrate has already been in unsupported mode?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "support mode" in the database, it is just that Microsoft will not give you support if you have a database that has been altered manually.

Essentially you are on your own if migration does or does not work...

Comment: That is precisely what my question is - how would MSFT know if the DB has been altered? Is there a flag in any of the content db's tables or a setting within SP or some magic that MSFT has not made public.

Comment: No flags, but if the problem is a big one they ask you to send over the content database and it would be pretty obvious if you were messing with it. Reading is not a problem, but if your reads cause locking and cause performance issues they will not be able to replicate the issue.